# How to find out the minimum and maximum usable CPU and memory space left on a kubernetes node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy Magento on a GCE `n1-standard-1` machine, but I keep getting the following error message.

```
pod (magento-magento-1486272877-zd34d) failed to fit in any node fit failure summary on nodes : Insufficient cpu (1)
```

I'm using the official [Magento helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/magento), and I've configured the `values.yml` file to contain very low CPU requests: `cpu: 25m`

When I look at the node details on the kubernetes dashboard, I see that my CPU is already spinning at `0.728` (72.80%) while it's not even doing anything besides the system containers. Also see image below:

[image: kubernetes standard n1-standard-1 resources]

Does this mean I have `1 - 0.728 = 0.272m` left for container requests? Then why is kubernetes still telling me that it has insufficient CPU when specifying `0.25m`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see that the CPU limits were `0.248` according to the picture in my post, so I put `cpu: 20m` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nifty kubectl command to get information about your nodes resources...

`kubectl top nodes`

And pods...

`kubectl top pods`

Pods with containers

`kubectl top pods --containers=true`